# Regex Find last word between comma

Tags: regex

I Have something like this : "my item1,item2,item3,item4,"

I just want as answer : "item4"

I use this :

```
    (?<=\,).*(?=\,$)
```

but it returns me : "item2,item3,item4"

How I can get only the last ?

I know that something with the lazy sign ? , but I'm not able to use it.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^,]*` instead of `.*` since `.` will also match the character comma. Here the non-greedy form `.*?` also won't work.

```
(?<=,)[^,]*(?=,$)
```

Comment: You can remove the lookbehind.

Comment: small diff mine asserts that there must be comma exists before the match but you'rs won't. You knows well..

Comment: Exactly, we can remove the lookbehind to have only : [^,]*(?=,$)

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion , you could also use the split command as follows :

```
x = "my item1,item2,item3,item4"
print x.split(",")[-1]
```

This will print the last element .